# Oracle BETWEEN DATE RANGE syntax correct

Tags: plsql

Good Day,

I have the following PL-SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    "FileProcessStatus"."ProcessStatusId"
    , "ProcessStatus"."Name"
    , COUNT("FileProcessStatus"."Id") AS Occurrences
FROM "FileProcessStatus" INNER JOIN "ProcessStatus" 
ON "FileProcessStatus"."ProcessStatusId" = "ProcessStatus"."Id"
GROUP BY "FileProcessStatus"."ProcessStatusId", "ProcessStatus"."Name"

WHERE "FileProcessStatus"."CreatedDate" 
BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-SEP-12','DD-MON-YY') AND TO_DATE('01-OCT-12','DD-MON-YY');
```

Now when I run the query *without* the WHERE clause, the query gives me the results I'm looking for, but when I include the WHERE BETWEEN because I'm trying to pull data out of two tables based on a date range, then I get the:

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.
```

I researched the problem and I understand the query's not formatted correctly, but I'm trying to stick to ANSI-SQL since I'm working with PL-SQL.

Suggestions, anyone?

TIA,

coson

Comment: Move the where above the group by and it'll work.

Comment: I tried that.  Now I got a

ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Answer (score 1):

The order of the SQL clauses is:

```
WITH     ...
SELECT   ...
FROM     ...
WHERE    ...    
GROUP BY ...
HAVING   ...    
ORDER BY ...
```